# ag-grid safari column move and enableCellTextSelection

Tags: ag-grid

I noticed that the following code, for Safari browser only, when moving the columns it selects all of the cells.  Also it is possible but hard to do, you can move all of the selected cells into the floating filter but this is an after affect of allowing the column move select all fields.

Setup
MacBook - Catalina 10.15
Browsers - FireFox/Edge/Chrome this issue isn't reproducible.

I was thinking of using: window.navigator.userAgent and identify if the browser was safari and to disable the feature for now but when invoking the command on some of the browsers it identifies Safari.
Ex: on Edge I get the following result
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36 Edg/85.0.564.70"

```
'use strict';
 
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { AgGridReact } from '@ag-grid-community/react';
import { AllCommunityModules } from '@ag-grid-community/all-modules';
import '@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import '@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
 
class GridExample extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 
 this.state = {
 modules: AllCommunityModules,
 columnDefs: [
 {
 field: 'athlete',
 minWidth: 200,
 },
 { field: 'age' },
 {
 field: 'country',
 minWidth: 150,
 },
 { field: 'year' },
 {
 field: 'date',
 minWidth: 150,
 },
 {
 field: 'sport',
 minWidth: 150,
 },
 { field: 'gold' },
 {
 field: 'silver',
 suppressPaste: true,
 },
 { field: 'bronze' },
 { field: 'total' },
 ],
 defaultColDef: {
 editable: true,
 floatingFilter: true,
 filter: true,
 flex: 1,
 minWidth: 100,
 resizable: true,
 },
 rowData: [],
 };
 }
 
 onGridReady = (params) => {
 this.gridApi = params.api;
 this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
 
 const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 const updateData = (data) => {
 this.setState({ rowData: data });
 };
 
 httpRequest.open(
 'GET',
 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/grid-packages/ag-grid-docs/src/olympicWinners.json'
 );
 httpRequest.send();
 httpRequest.onreadystatechange = () => {
 if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
 updateData(JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText));
 }
 };
 };
 
 render() {
 return (
 <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
 <div
 id="myGrid"
 style={{
 height: '100%',
 width: '100%',
 }}
 className="ag-theme-alpine"
 >
 <AgGridReact
 modules={this.state.modules}
 columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
 defaultColDef={this.state.defaultColDef}
 ensureDomOrder={true}
 enableCellTextSelection={true}
 onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
 rowData={this.state.rowData}
 />
 </div>
 </div>
 );
 }
}
 
render(<GridExample></GridExample>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```